# How can I create a polar plot on a Cartesian grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

I'm currently using `tikzpicture` and `pgfplots` to plot [this polar function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%5E2%20=%20r%5E4%28sin%5E4%28theta%29%20%2b%20cos%5E4%28theta%29%29):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}
    \addplot[red,domain=0:360,samples=360,smooth] (x,{sqrt(4/(cos(4*x)+3))});
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, this plots it on a polar axis, which doesn't really make sense in context. (It's defined implicitly as x<sup>4</sup> + y<sup>4</sup> = x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> and I'm just using polar coordinates to easily plot it.)

How can I get the same nice graph with the correct Cartesian grid, as Wolfram|Alpha displays it?

I considered `\begin{polaraxis}[hide axis]` and an additional `\begin{axis}` but that seems like it would require manual alignment, etc.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example please?

Comment: @NictraSavios done.

Comment: @WChargin: Christian's answer is much better, it would be best if you could accept that instead of mine, so I can delete mine.

Comment: @Jake You're right that in this case it's nice to have a dedicated option. However, I appreciate that you can do arbitrary transforms, so it might be good to keep your answer too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can tell `pgfplots` that the input is actually given in polar coordinates using `data cs=polar`. Pgfplots will automatically transform it to the output coordinate system:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image,
    enlargelimits=true,
     ]
    \addplot[data cs=polar,red,domain=0:360,samples=360,smooth] (x,{sqrt(4/(cos(4*x)+3))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This key can also be used to provide cartesian coordinates in polar axis or other variations.

Answer (score 20):

You can transform the polar coordinates to cartesian using an `x filter` and a `y filter`. If you wrap those in a style like this:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    interpret as polar/.style={
            x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{cos(rawx)*rawy},
            y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{sin(rawx)*rawy}
        }
}
```

you can just add `interpret as polar` to your `\addplot` options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    interpret as polar/.style={
            x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{cos(rawx)*rawy},
            y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{sin(rawx)*rawy}
        }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            axis equal image,
            enlargelimits=true
        ]
    \addplot[
            red, thick,
            domain=0:360,
            samples=360,
            smooth,
            interpret as polar
        ] (x,{sqrt(4/(cos(4*x)+3))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```