# Polar Coordinates Graph using TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, coordinates, polarplot

I have to create a Tikz picture of a limacon which is given in polar coordinates by the equation r = 0.5 + cos(θ) for θ between 0 and 2π.
Note:makethe x-axis between 0.2 and 1.7 with a scale of 3 and the y-axis between 1 and 1 with a scale of 3.

My document is of the form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=3, yscale=3, domain=-0.2:1.7]

\draw[<->] (-0.2, 0) -- (1.7, 0)

 node[above]{$x$};

\draw[<->] (0,0) -- (0,5)

 node[right]{$y$};

\draw[colour=purple, smooth]

 plot(HERE);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, I do not know how to write the function in '' plot(HERE); ''.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SZ. You can highlight code blocks by either indenting them four spaces or selecting them and hitting `{}` in the gui for the editor.

Comment: Does [Tikz picture of limaçon](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247462) solve your problem?